# MPMoviePlayer not working

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am working with a video app in iphone.
when a user hits a button it will lead to second view and from there I am playing a video from a url.

But when user return back from that view and agin go to that the video is not playing.

It shows the below 2 lines continuously

```
     [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
     [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
```

Here is my code

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
[super viewDidLoad];


 self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
self.moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[[self.moviePlayerController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(-30, 72, 360,140)];


[[self view] addSubview: [self.moviePlayerController view]];


  NSString *strng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://quickemee_videos.s3.amazonaws.com/videoStream_1352395870143_616.mp4"];

NSLog(@"strng %@",strng);
NSURL * adurl = [NSURL URLWithString:strng];

 [self playVideo:adurl];

 }
```

.
.
.
.

```
 -(IBAction)back:(id)sender{


 [moviePlayerController stop];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video_name" ofType:@"m4v"]];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer play];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:FALSE];
// if you want no control.
    [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `[self prepareToPlay]` first.

Apple says:

> If a movie player is not already prepared to play when you call the
>   play method, that method automatically calls this method. However, to
>   minimize playback delay, call this method before you call play.

**Update:**

Make sure the file is available. I can't access it in my browser.

Comment: you mean,before allocating movie player ?

Comment: you cant..because it is a local server,
k..I will update my question with a live url

Comment: Can your application definitely access the file though? Try opening it in safari.

Comment: yep..for the first time I can access that, can see the video
check my updated url..

Answer (score 1):

The `viewDidLoad` is called only once. So when you pop your viewController and then return back to it, `viewDidLoad` is not called again. So try implementing `self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];` in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: dude..After pop,viewDidLoad will be called again

Comment: are you sure? Coz the last time I tried, it didnt call viewDidLoad